# Can I omit "the" in (see also section "Special warnings and precautions for use")

Tags: articles

A phrase from a package insert:

> A similar effect may arise due to the poor general health of the patient, as well as due to seriously compromised liver or kidney function (see also section “Special warnings and precautions for use”)

Is it okay as it is, or should one use **the** here?

> A similar effect may arise due to the poor general health of the patient, as well as due to seriously compromised liver or kidney function (see also **the** section “Special warnings and precautions for use”)

Does the "headlinese-style omission of articles" apply to parenthetical constructions?

Comment: It's not a headline  it's an instruction. As in *bring water to boil and add egg*. Or perhaps it just wonky English. Who wrote it? The same people who write fortune cookie inserts?

Comment: @AlanCarmack - so the-dropping is okay?

Comment: @AlanCarmack - I am the proud author of this sentence. Trying my hand at translation.

Comment: I would say  "See: Special warnings and precautions for use " if it's a heading.

Comment: If "Special warnings and precautions for use” is a link to a different webpage (or section title in a typed paper) you don't need to use *section* before it. Just say *See "Special warnings and precautions for use”*, and ditch the quotation marks if it is a link.

Comment: @AlanCarmack - thank you. I noticed this usage when googling, but I was curious about the use of "the" with "section" here. I also noticed that "section" is used when there is a number: "(see also Section 3.4 "Special warnings and precautions for use")", so indeed there may be no need for the word 'section' in my case. Still my article curiousity got the better of me.

Comment: A case can be made for either using *the* or not using *the*. We often use  something like *See Section IX.Ib.32c*, and using *the* would not be my advice in this case. So one can transfer that line of reasoning to your sections, which happen to have text, not numerics. Or you could justify nonuse of *the* along the lines I already mentioned, viz a recipe instruction,  or from note-taking English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically we say "See section {section-identifier}".

for example

> See section §4.3.2

The phrase "Special warnings and precautions for use” is being used as an identifier.

You could also write:

> See "Special warnings and precautions for use”

or

> See the section entitled "Special warnings and precautions for use”

With an identifier, you would not use the definite article.

See page 23.

See chapter 17.

See the chapter on Boiler Repair.